# How to protect encryption key from server admin?

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, passwords

**Scenario**

- Data is encrypted inside DB using key that is never stored in the app server or DB server
- Key is entered upon login and is stored via `$_COOKIE['key']` variable for persistence (so user doesn't have to enter it every page load)
- Data is decrypted via `$_COOKIE['key']`
- `$_COOKIE['key']` is destroyed upon browser exit

**Threat**

Rouge server admin snoops on PHP files, finds out key is stored at `$_COOKIE['key']`. He injects malicious code like `email_me($_COOKIE['key']);`. He erase malicious code after gaining the key.

**Question**

Is there a way to protect yourself from this kind of scenario?

Comment: You could perform the decryption client-wise.  i.e. the server will return you data that is still encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it harder for a server admin to get the key, but they always can.

Let's think about moving the encryption and decryption to the client side. Now, the server won't get the key, so the server admin should not be able to decrypt the data. That's not quite true, because the server admin can manipulate the page JavaScript so that either the key is sent to the server or nothing is encrypted at all.

The only way a client can be certain that a server admin cannot steal their data, is by using a client software that is open source and cannot be changed on-the-fly by an admin. So, web pages and automatically updating apps are out of the question.

Comment: `cannot be changed on-the-fly by an admin` how is this possible if the admin has root?

Comment: A sever admin can read the key from memory (if you, for example, use an encrypted loop device), the admin can replay (and modify) TCP streams to talk to any client and falsify answers.

Comment: @IMB  As I said, this would not be possible to prevent for web pages, but actual applications that are running on the client machine usually go over multiple eyes. Of course, in that case the person building the application could introduce some malicious code. If the software were open source and the build pipeline would produce reproducible builds, you would at least be able to detect malicious manipulation of client code.

Comment: @grochmal Ideally, data is encrypted and decrypted on the client along with integrity checking through MAC verification. A client would detect bad responses (something they didn't encrypt before). Of course, nothing can prevent a denial of services that is triggered by a server admin.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I guess your proposed solution is not possible for us since we are using web apps. So we just have to trust the admins then?

Comment: @IMB Trust your admins, pay them well, do something for the [SysAdmin day](http://sysadminday.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If the key itself is a concern, you can use cryptography oracles like Keyvault in Azure that never release the keys contained within but perform cryptography themselves on data sent to them.

Of course an admin would be able to access the data as long as they have access to the cryptography oracle, but not afterwards, and they would never have the key. This helps in some scenarios, that's the whole point of services like Azure Keyvault. Also you don't need to give actual access to the encryption service to all admins.

Another mitigation (a detective control, as opposed to a preventive one) is audit logging both on the IT and application level. When done right, not even admins can hide the fact that they accessed the data, which again can help mitigate some risks and at least may provide non-repudiation.

Yet another thing you could do is proper change management, controlling who has access (especially write access) to your source code. This can get difficult with script languages like PHP, where you can't really sign code, but you can still have good processes for reviewing and releasing code to production.

So in the end, it's probably less of a technical question, there's a great deal you can do in terms of processes.

Comment: The admin would not get the key, but would get all decrypted data nevertheless.

Comment: That's correct, but in a more controlled, audited, timebound way only, and that's a significant difference in some cases (and it's probably not in others).

Comment: What it comes down to is an application user inherently trusts the abstract notion of the "application developer". However, what exactly that means is very important. Do I inherently trust the cleaning staff of the development company too, because they had access to production servers and there was no logical access control at all? Or do I only trust a small set of production admins, who work in a controlled, audited environment, with well-designed processes to prevent (internal) abuse? That makes the difference.

Comment: In a bank I once worked the HSM (hardware encryption) always went down on thursday nights for some 20-30 minutes.  It turned out that the cleaners disconnected the network cables to clean the shelves better.  And Thursday was server room cleaning day.